# Rails 'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path. ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I am following section 4 (Server Side Concerns) to set up ajax on a page.  I've copied the tutorial text completely (replacing the model names with my own) and it creates and saves my "Participants" record, but does not automatically refresh the ajax partial.

This is the error I get...which looks like it's referrring to my create.js.erb

```
ActionView::Template::Error ('nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.):
    1: $("<%= escape_javascript(render @participant) %>").appendTo("#participants");
    2: // $('#participants').html("<%= j (render @participants) %>");
  app/views/participants/create.js.erb:2:in `_app_views_participants_create_js_erb___1675277149181037111_70181034249880'
```

Here's my code

```
class ParticipantsController < ApplicationController
def new
  @participant = Participant.new
  @participants = @participants.recently_updated
end

def create
  @participant = Participant.new(participant_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @participant.save
      format.html { redirect_to @participant, notice: 'Helper Invited!' }
      format.js   {}
      format.json { render json: @participant, status: :created, location: @participant }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @participant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<ul id="participants">
  <%= render @participants %>
 </ul>

<%= form_for(@participant, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :email %><br>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>
<%= f.submit 'SUBMIT' %> 
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  return $("#new_participant").on("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
    return $("#new_participant").append(xhr.responseText);
  }).on("ajax:error", function(e, xhr, status, error) {
    return $("#new_participant").append("<p>Oops.  Please Try again.</p>");
  });
});
 </script>
 <script>
$(function() {
  return $("a[data-remote]").on("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
    return alert("The helper has been removed and notified.");
  });
});
</script>
```

_participant.html.erb

```
<li >
<%= participant.email %> <%= link_to participant, remote: true, method: :delete,  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>REMOVE<% end %>
</li>
```

create.js.erb

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render @participant) %>").appendTo("#participants");
```

destroy.js.erb

```
$('#participants').html("<%= j (render @participants) %>");
```

Comment: CHeck if you are getting `@participant` in `create.js.erb` file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's on line 2 of your `create.js.erb` file, it's the missing `@participants` not the `@participant`.

You've commented the line out in JS, but the ERB is still going to be processed by Rails, so it's still trying to do the `render @participants`

#### Update

For future... it's the last line of that error that's the key:

```
app/views/participants/create.js.erb:2
```

See the `2` at the end, that's telling you which line the error happened on, and so that's where you need to focus when looking for the problem.

Comment: That works....meaning it refreshes and shows the new record, but it puts this error under the just used form: $("
\n\n :sample@email.com \n <\/i> REMOVE<\/span>\n\n \n<\/a><\/li>\n\n").appendTo("#participants");

Comment: So you need to accept my answer as solving this question, and then ask a new question about your new problem if you need to.

Comment: I've posted the second question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034208/extra-javascript-code-posting-under-form-after-ajax-rails-form-submit-n-n-e

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this error on my end. I had missed creating the action in the controller.

So in your example, I would have missed the create action in the controller. Thus, when testing anything using that action, it would fail.

Any future users experiencing this issue, make sure the action is defined and no errors/typos in the controller level.