# Extra Javascript code posting under Form after Ajax Rails form submit ( \n\n...etc)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am following section 4 (Server Side Concerns) to set up ajax on a page.  I've copied the tutorial text completely (replacing the model names with my own) and it creates and saves my "Participants" record and refreshes the partial....but it posts this weird code below the just submitted form:

```
$("
\n\n    Helper:sampleemail@sample.com \n<\/li>\n\n").appendTo("#participants");
```

This seems to be some sort of weird mash-up of my partial information and my creat.js. It's not really an error...just extra code.

Here's my code

```
class ParticipantsController < ApplicationController
def new
  @participant = Participant.new
  @participants = @participants.recently_updated
end

def create
  @participant = Participant.new(participant_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @participant.save
      format.html { redirect_to @participant, notice: 'Helper Invited!' }
      format.js   {}
      format.json { render json: @participant, status: :created, location: @participant }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @participant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<ul id="participants">
  <%= render @participants %>
 </ul>

<%= form_for(@participant, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :email %><br>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>
<%= f.submit 'SUBMIT' %> 
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  return $("#new_participant").on("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
    return $("#new_participant").append(xhr.responseText);
  }).on("ajax:error", function(e, xhr, status, error) {
    return $("#new_participant").append("<p>Oops.  Please Try again.</p>");
  });
});
 </script>
 <script>
$(function() {
  return $("a[data-remote]").on("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
    return alert("The helper has been removed and notified.");
  });
});
</script>
```

_participant.html.erb

```
<li >
<%= participant.email %> <%= link_to participant, remote: true, method: :delete,  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>REMOVE<% end %>
</li>
```

create.js.erb

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render @participant) %>").appendTo("#participants");
```

destroy.js.erb

```
$('#participants').html("<%= j (render @participants) %>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are both responding with a `js.erb` file and listening for the `ajax:success` event. You should only need to do one. Right now the `ajax:success` listener is appending the response to the form and the response is javascript code. Remove that listener and you should get the desired results.